# WebDriver not able to locate element by xpath using Java

Tags: java, html, xpath

I've been working at this for some time now. I'm using `Selenium` and `WebDriver version 2.45` (with all browsers). I'm using Java, which should be arbitrary.

What I'm doing is simply find an element and hover over it, which I have done in earlier code. But for some reason, I can't get this one to work. I'm trying to get an element with this xpath, obtained by right-clicking the element in the HTML in Chrome and clicking "`copy xpath`":

```
.//*[@id='at-container']/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/input[4]
```

What I have tried and did not work:

```
WebElement userName_editbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='formelements' and @name='login']"));

WebElement userName_editbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='at-container']/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/input[4]]"));
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: What is not working? Hover over? Element can't be located?